Looking for novel about a living museum
I am looking for a book that I have a vague recollection of reading in English at school (mid-1990s, so definitely no more recent than 1996) in the UK, though I am not too sure of many details. Here is what I (think) I can remember:
The main protagonist (probably a teen,) either has to help look after an area within their 'world' or discovers that there are many large areas within their world.
It turns out that the 'world' is in fact a living museum, and that each area is a different exhibit that outsiders can come and view. Each area contains people that believe they are living in said era, when in fact they are either cloned/genetically engineered/synthetic and were created to be a part of the museum exhibit. Quite possibly one of the exhibits was WWII.
At the end the protagonist discovers

 they are also one of those created for the use of the museum.

This has been bothering me for years, and starting to think that I maybe dreamed it.

Are the "outsiders" human or aliens?

@DavidW, I believe they're all human.

A Rag, A Bone and A Hank of Hair by Nicholas Fisk? It was published in 1980."A thrilling futuristic novel set at the end of the 22nd century. The government is cloning new people and has manufactured a 1940s wartime family who are unaware that nothing they know is real. Our hero is sent to monitor these 'Reborns' and gradually becomes aware of a horrible underlying secret. A brilliant plot twist at the end turns the book on its head"

@sueelleker That's the book - post it as an answer. user3371379 the protagonist is called Brin and he realises he is a Reborn because his armpit keeps itching. "A Reborn!’ Brin thought. ‘That’s what I am! I should have guessed earlier. The itching should have told me. I wonder how long ago they made me? It can’t have been long. Otherwise the pinpricks in my armpit would have healed more completely, they wouldn’t still itch from being so new. Fool, why didn’t I guess?"

A Rag, A Bone and A Hank of Hair by Nicholas Fisk. It was published in 1980."A thrilling futuristic novel set at the end of the 22nd century. The government is cloning new people and has manufactured a 1940s wartime family who are unaware that nothing they know is real. Our hero is sent to monitor these 'Reborns' and gradually becomes aware of a horrible underlying secret. A brilliant plot twist at the end turns the book on its head" –

that sounds really promising, thanks. The title has a hint of familiarity to it, though looking at the book covers on Google I'm not seeing anything that rings a bell. The plot certainly seems to match so I'll try and get a copy and confirm. Thanks again.

Having now read the book I'm convinced it's the right one... there was a lot more to it than I remembered and though not strictly a 'museum' the 'reborns' in the scenario (not exhibit) were definitely being watched and studied! Thanks again for helping me find a book that has bothered me for years!
